# Run a script inside a docker container that instantiates another docker container

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I have two docker images in a linux machine. One is running jenkins and the other a nodejs service. The jenkins is conneted to a gitlab account so in my pipeline by using

```
git branch: 'master', credentialsId: '6bc7-41b5-a1d9-2583489ad967', url: 'https://gitlab.com/myservice'
```

every time I build the project I have the latest git version in my host folder jenkins_home/workspace/MyJenkinsItem/myservicerepo. The docker image that has the jenkins runs with the following command:

```
docker run --rm -d --name jenkins -v $MYPATH/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

In the nodejs project in the host machine I have a bash script that copies the files from jenkins_home/workspace/MyJenkinsItem/myservicerepo (host machine) to a folder of my choice (e.g. /mypath/nodejs). Then it builds a docker image by using a Dockerfile and run the service I want.

What I would like to do is to automate the process from jenkins. This means every time I build the jenkins pipeline from my jenkins container I have to access the script in /mypath/nodejs and run in another container all the project in /mypath/nodejs.

I'm not sure how I could do that. What I have tried is to copy

```
docker run --rm -d --name jenkins  -v $MYPATH/nodejs/jenkins-script.sh:/var/scripts/jenkins-script.sh -v $MYPATH/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

but I have a jenkins error that the jenkins_script.sh cannot find specific folders in the container. It seems as if I have to mount everything of the nodejs inside my jenkins container and instantiate the nodejs container from there?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this post about running CI in docker, https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci?

Comment: I have found something similar and what it's being suggested is to mount the docker command, ie. docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker.  However I get permission denied as there are no enough permissions

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I had to start jenkins I had to mount the docker sock and the folder that had all the files for the docker container, i.e. Dockerfile, package.json for the nodejs etc. So what I did was:

```
docker run --rm -d --name jenkins \
        -v MyNodeJSPAth/myfolder:MyNodeJSPAth/myfolder \
        -v MyPATH/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
        -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
        -p 8081:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Furthermore because I had permission denied on the docker command inside the jenkins container I changed the permissions of the docker.sock in /var/run to

```
chmod o+xw /var/run/docker.sock
```

However you could also create/use a current user to the docker container that has access to the /var/run/docker.sock, but I haven't used it.